# JAVA: why Object [] obj = {new Object[1],new Object[2]} and not other classes?

Tags: java

Hi I have seen that `Object [] obj = {new Object[1],new Object[2]}` is allowed and I am not sure why it is.  If I use other classes instead of `Object` it's generating errors (like Integer, or ArrayList, or even my classes like `Grandpa`, `Dad` and `Me`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since even an `Object[]` is an object that's why its not throwing any error. But in reality, what you're actually doing is assigning an array to an `Object`.

```
Object[][] obj = {new Object[1],new Object[2]}; // proper way
Object[] obj = {new Object[1],new Object[2]}; // this works because Object[] is treated as an Object
```

That won't work in the case of `String` or anything else as each element in a `String` array has to be a String and not a `String` array.

```
String[][] obj = {new String[1],new String[2]}; // proper way as its a 2d array where each element in itself is a 1d array.
String[] obj = {new String[1],new String[2]}; // this won't because each element in String array must be a String
String[] obj = {new String("1"),new String("2")}; // this will work as each element is a string
```

Answer (score 2):

Your signature satisfied the condition, *an array of any Objects*.

```
Object [] obj = {new Object[1],new Object[2]}
```

Because  `new Object[1]`  is an `Array`  and That is also an `Object`, Since every `Class extends Object`

Answer (score 0):

`obj` is just an Object array here. Also `Array` is a `Object` too So what is the issue. Object is a base class for any class in Java.

```
Object [] obj = {Element Should be Objects}
```

So `Array` is an Object too.

Answer (score 0):

`Object [] obj = {Can have any type of Object because every class by default extends Object Class}`

`X [] obj = { Array of objects of X Class}`

Example:

> String[] obj = { Array of String Objects}
>
> Granpa[] gandobj = { Array of Granpa Objects}